# this.refs.something returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, react-ref

I have an element with a `ref` that is defined and ends up getting rendered into the page :

```
    <div ref="russian" ...>
       ...
    </div>
```

I want to access the DOM element properties like `offset...` or something. However, I keep getting `undefined` and I haven't the faintest idea why. After some searching it's clear that `refs` are only applicable to one file but I'm not using this anywhere besides this one page. I'm saying this to log it:

`console.log('REFS', this.refs.russian);`

What could be causing this?

Comment: this.refs would be the string "russian" (assuming you're in the right scope), not an object, so it wouldn't have a property of "russian"

Comment: @Pamblam in reactjs ref is a reference to an element dom. It becomes accessible as an object

Comment: Also it would help to see more code. Ref is only accessible to the object it binds to. In most cases you would have to bind it to element that its coming from

Comment: ref is not traditional scope binding, it's owner-ownee relationship.

Comment: What version of React? Prior to 14, you had to use `refs.getDOMNode()` IIRC

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The correct place to work with `refs` is inside specific React lifecycle methods e.g. [ComponentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount), [ComponentDidUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate)

You cannot reference `refs` from the `render()` method. [Read more about the cautions of working with `refs` here.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#cautions)

If you move your `console.log('REFS', this.refs.russian);` call to `ComponentDidMount` or `ComponentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods (assuming you are on React >= 14) you should not get *undefined* as a result.

UPDATE: *also refs will not work on **stateless components** per the caution link above*

Answer (score 44):

Check that you are not accessing ref before the child component has been mounted. E.g. it doesn't work in `componentWillMount`. A different pattern which auto invokes ref related callback after the element has been mounted is this-

```
<div ref={(elem)=>(console.log(elem))}/>
```

You can use this notation to get mounted elements in deep nesting as well -

```
<div ref={this.props.onMounted}/>
```

Answer (score 9):

Update since React version 16.4

In your constructor method define your ref like this

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.russian = React.createRef();
}
```

In your render where you are using `ref` do this.

```
<input
  name="russian"
  ref={this.russian} // Proper way to assign ref in react ver 16.4
/>
```

For e.g if you want to have focus when component mounts do this

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.russian); 
  this.russian.current.focus();
 }
```

Reference [Refs Documentation React](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue in my form validation methods, trying to assign `this.ref.current.reportValidity()`

Writing the method I was doing this in as `validate = () => {}` instead of `validate() {}` helped me out, but I'm not totally sure why exactly, just something I remembered from habits I had in my past work experience that gave me this. Hope it helps and could someone kindly clarify this answer with why this might work exactly.

Comment: use an arrow function to wrap around an event handler, This is equivalent to calling .bind(Binding methods helps ensure that the second snippet works the same way as the first one)
When you need to invoke a function prop with an argument, you should always specify a fat arrow function that invokes the prop, React will evaluate the expression when the component renders its content, which will invoke the prop even though the user hasn’t clicked the button element. This is rarely the intended effect and can cause unexpected behaviors or produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting class withStyle, please remove and export default nomally.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your Console.log inside the function `example(){...}` you should put it inside:

```
example=()=>{....}
```

Comment: why do it this way?