# React Native: why is component ref undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ref, react-ref

I have the following code in my React Native app:

```
<View>
    <ToolBar
        ButtonRightText={"Submit"}
        onRightButtonPress = {(event) => {
            const form = this.cForm.wrappedInstance.wrappedInstance;
        }}
    />
    <ComponentForm 
        ref={(connectView) => {
            this.cForm = connectView
        }}
    />
</View>
```

This is a screen that contains `<Toolbar>` at the top, and `<ComponentForm>` below it. When the screen loads, the callback in `<ComponentForm>` is called, and `connectView` is an object like I expect. However, when I click the `Submit` button in `<Toolbar>`, it calls its callback which indicates that `this.cForm` is `undefined`.

So the problem is that `this.cForm` does get set when the screen loads, but then when I click `Submit`, `this.cForm` is undefined.

Anyone know how I can approach debugging this?

Comment: What is `this` actually? Is that piece of code inside of a class components render?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [this.refs.something returns "undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230020/this-refs-something-returns-undefined)